# C++11 constructor & destructor order

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, operator-overloading, destructor

I have the code below which gives me the following output:

> Constructing stream s1
>   Destructing stream s1
>   Output1
>   Test
>   Constructing stream s2
>   Destructing stream s2
>   Test

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using std::cout;

class Stream {
public:
    Stream(const std::string &name) : s(name) {
        cout << "Constructing stream " << name <<  std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Stream(){
        cout << "Destructing stream " << s << std::endl;
    }

    friend Stream &&operator<<(Stream &&rhs, const std::string &str) {
        cout << str << std::endl;
        return std::move(rhs);
    }

    std::string s;
};

Stream &&getStream(const std::string &name){
    Stream stream(name);
    return std::move(stream);
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    getStream("s1") << "Output1" << "Test";
    getStream("s2") << "Test";
}
```

My expectation for the output was this:

> Constructing stream s1
>  Output1
>  Test
>  Destructing stream s1
>  Constructing stream s2
>  Test
>  Destructing stream s2

Why is there a call to the destructor before the << operator call?

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour because you're returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: A change to Stream getStream(const std::string &name) changes the behaviour to:

Constructing stream s1
Destructing stream s1
Output1
Test
Destructing stream s1
Constructing stream s2
Destructing stream s2
Test
Destructing stream s2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kerrek has pointed out correctly, the cause is this function:

```
Stream &&getStream(const std::string &name){
    Stream stream(name);
    return std::move(stream);
}
```

Here you create an object of type "Stream" as *local* variable "stream". When the function returns, the variable "stream" is destructed. This obviously happends before "Output1" is printed.